# Excel VBA Display +/- according to value

Tags: vba, excel

this is calculating number of % of increased/decrease:

```
Dim YLDPercent As String
YLDPercent = FormatNumber(((YLD - YldLW) / YLD) * 100, 2) & "%"
```

how can I make it display + when the number is positive? I might do that via IF but I guess there will be easier of doing it.

Thanks

P.

Comment: it does automatically display the `-` when there is a decrease so it seems like you only have one condition to add a `+` in front of the number when it's positive. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: "+0.00%;-0.00%" is not working. I need to do the same for like 10 values so the simple solution will be more welcomed

Comment: @user3361013 can you clarify how it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Dim YLDPercent As String
YLDPercent = Format((YLD - YldLW) / YLD, "+0.00%;-0.00%")
```

note that I removed `* 100`, since `%` format automatically changes `1` to `100%`

Comment: what is the values of your `YLD` and `YldLW`?

Comment: sorry, I've forgot to change formatnumber to .format now it is working